# does the `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` use cookies in django

Tags: python, django, cookies, requestcontext

when i change the homepage view:

```
def home(request):
    return render_to_response('homepage.html')
```

to

```
def home(request):
    return render_to_response('homepage.html',context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

the `user` who login my site will always login  even when i close the web Browser(firefox)

why `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` can do this ?  Does it use cookies ?

how long time it will maintain this state .

thanks

the homepage.html is :

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Welcome, {{ user.username }}. Thanks for logging in.</p>
{% else %}
    <p>Welcome, new user. Please <a href="/account/login_view">login</a></p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding the RequestContext does not change the user's logged-in state at all. And your question about cookies makes no sense at all. What the RequestContext does is make certain variables accessible in the template context - among them, assuming you have the `auth` context processor enabled, is a `user` variable.

Without the RequestContext, the user is still logged in, but you don't pass the `user` variable to the context, so your `if` statement evaluates to False. Nothing to do with the user's actual status at all.

Comment: thanks Daniel , but why the user always logged-in even when i close the firefox .  Does it saves this state  to database  .

Answer (score 0):

If you add `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` context from the [context processors](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) you have defined in your `settings.py` will be added to the template, in your case this includes the current user object in `user`.
If you remove it, the variable doesn't exist, but inside the template this doesn't raise an exception but the HTML for the not-logged in user is rendered!

The user information is stored in a [session](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/), which uses cookies.